# Is there any way, to set up dualboot on Android devices?

Tags: dual-boot

I would like to dualboot my phone, because I'm making a custom ROM. Is possible to have a stable system on the built-in storage and my custom ROM in development on my SD card? And if yes, how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few apps in the early Android days, but they took too much memory.

You're better off just using a Nandroid backup and restoring between systems. If you just swap the system and boot, it'll be quicker and you can work on as many ROMs as you want.

I used to run CM9, CM11, and CM12 when I was still working out CM 12.

Comment: What about 7 years later when devices typically have more storage?